# What apps offer the best ROI for city government?

Tags: government

I work in a government agency. At a town hall.

I'm looking for ideas and suggestions involving technology and GIS maps. What are the trends that are up in the public sector?

What is the relative [return on investment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_on_investment) (ROI) for applications in these areas: health, transit, education, social welfare, sport and recreation, culture, youth, housing, public safety, urban mobility, sewage, environment, disaster management, environmental management, urban economy, rural economy, management PMI , community governance.

Comment: Please edit this question to make it more specific: in its current form it is too broad to be answerable.  Additional advice is available at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask and in our [faq].

Comment: Thank you! I liked the tips. I thought that this book can help me too: http://esripress.esri.com/display/index.cfm?fuseaction=display&websiteID=100

Answer (score 5):

In my experience the most prominent areas of GIS application for city/county governments are utilities mapping (power/sewer/gas), property boundaries (parcel lines), and transportation (roads/bridges/signs).  Second to those are keeping track of information pertinent to dispatching emergency services (fire/police/ambulance).

All of these can be specialties within GIS and are very broad topics, each with their own intricacies.

EDIT (To better reflect the edited question):
As far as ROI goes, I would start with [ESRI's site that focuses on ROI](http://roi.esri.com/), although bear in mind that they have a vested interest in making GIS look as fantastic as possible.  In my experience ROI is highly dependent on the experience of the GIS managers and the field users.